# "no screens found" on Acer Aspire V5-122; Live Disk

Tags: acer, touchscreen, live-environment

Trying to do a 13.04 Live Desk on Acer Aspire v5-122, which has the touch screen. Seems to be going OK at first, but then drops to command prompt with the X server reporting that no screens can be found. I saw someone else on here had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the install option, make sure you connect to WiFi during installation, reboot, and install the AMD driver from the terminal. Once you boot into the installed system, it'll go into a command line. If not, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

Log in to the prompt.

Run:

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
unzip amd*
## Login as root:
sudo su 
## Run the drivers installer:
./amd*.run
```

It will then open the proprietary AMD driver installer, agree to the terms, allow it to install, then run:

```
sudo reboot
```

At the prompt. Hope this helps!

Source: http://justanyone.blogspot.com/2013/08/solved-installing-linux-on-acer-aspire.html?m=1